# Need experienced help coding product variants/ list elements like ones on other sites. Working on Wix API

Tags: json, schema, ld, formwizard

I need help coding something for my Wix website I found on another website and need to speak to someone experienced.

I want to know how to code a page like these ones I linked.
(https://stickerapp.com/stickers/hang-tag-stickers)
(https://stickerapp.com/stickers/sticker-sheets#!)

I just wish I knew how I get these itemized lists onto my site and insert the products I offer. But these detailed lists would be perfect for my e-commerce site!

I have been studying the back end of the site for a few weeks now to see exactly how by looking at source codes and googling them. I've taken some web courses, done research and have experimented in coding playgrounds, but still having such trouble achieve the desired result!

[I just wish I knew how I get these itemized lists onto my site with the products I offer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avfyw.png)

[I have been studying the back end of the site for a few weeks now to see exactly what needs to be done by looking at source codes and googling them. I've taken some web courses, done research and have experimented in coding playgrounds, but still having such trouble achieve the desired result!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbXhn.png)]